# gnuplot logical expression evaluation

Tags: gnuplot

This is about gnuplot Version 4.6 patchlevel 6.

My (rather complex) scripts for an older gnuplot version behaves strangely with this new 4.6. This illustrates the very basic cause of everything:

```
gnuplot> print 7 == 07
1
gnuplot> print 8 == 08
0

gnuplot> print 8 == 08
                     ^
         ';' expected

gnuplot> print 8 == 8
1
```

That is, the expression 8 == 08 renders 0 (False) followed by a syntax error (';' expected), while 7 == 07 does not.

I would be pleased for an explanation for that.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers starting with `0` are interpreted as octal literals. Octal number contains digits `0-7`, so `8` is a syntax error.

Comment: I see... writing "08" or '08' instead of simply 08 solves the issue. Thanks. I just do not know if it is related to gnuplot version (because with gp 4.2 things worked all fine) or an OS related issue (used to be Red Hat, now it is Debian Jessie). I'll try to find out.